# Fix Peer validation failed for user in postgres 10 with puppet script

Tags: postgresql, puppet, rhel7

I've been trying to set up a Postgres server in a RHEL7 VM with Puppet in standalone mode. The thing is i just cannot manage to connect with the user, all the tables get created correctly and when trying to connect to the user got:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user
```

Even after reading and trying several different configurations for the hba_config, just cannot make this to work

Puppetfile:

```
class profile::tdms::postgresql (
    String $pgsql_password,
    String $pg_db_username,
    String $pg_db_password,
    String $emsa_tdm_db = 'emsa_tdms_django',
    String $airflow_db = 'emsa_tdms_airflow',
    String $celery_db = 'emsa_tdms_celery',

) {
    include epel

    class { 'postgresql::globals':
        manage_package_repo => true,
        version             => '10',
    }

    class { 'postgresql::server':
        postgres_password => $pgsql_password,
    }
    notice("PSQL PASS: ${pgsql_password}, PGSQL DB PASS: ${pg_db_password}, PSQL USER: ${pg_db_username}")

# Postgis instalation. Not working
#     class { 'postgresql::server::postgis':
#     package_name => 'postgis25_10'
#    }

    postgresql::server::role { $pg_db_username:
    username        => $pg_db_username,
    #password_hash   => postgresql_password($pg_db_username, $pg_db_password),
    update_password => $pg_db_password,
    replication     => true
    }


    postgresql::server::db { $airflow_db:
        user     => $pg_db_username,
        password => postgresql_password($pg_db_username, $pg_db_password),
        owner    => $pg_db_username
        #password => $pg_db_password
    }
    -> postgresql::server::db { $emsa_tdm_db:
        user     => $pg_db_username,
        password => postgresql_password($pg_db_username, $pg_db_password),
        #password => $pg_db_password
        owner    => $pg_db_username
    }
    -> postgresql::server::db { $celery_db:
        user     => $pg_db_username,
        password => postgresql_password($pg_db_username, $pg_db_password),
        #password => $pg_db_password
        owner    => $pg_db_username
    }


    -> postgresql::server::extension { 'airflow_postgis':
        database  => $airflow_db,
        extension => 'postgis',
    }
    -> postgresql::server::extension { 'tdm_postgis':
        database  => $emsa_tdm_db,
        extension => 'postgis',
    }
    # postgresql::server::pg_hba_rule { 'local unix sockets':
    #     description => 'local is for Unix domain socket connections only',
    #     type        => 'local',
    #     database    => 'all',
    #     user        => 'all',
    #     address     => '',
    #     auth_method => 'peer',
    # }
    postgresql::server::pg_hba_rule { 'IPv4 local 1':
        description => 'IPv4 local connections',
        type        => 'host',
        database    => 'all',
        user        => $pg_db_username,
        address     => '0.0.0.0/0',
        auth_method => 'md5',
    }
    postgresql::server::pg_hba_rule { 'IPv4 local 2':
        type        => 'host',
        database    => 'all',
        user        => 'all',
        address     => '127.0.0.1/32',
        auth_method => 'ident',
    }
    postgresql::server::pg_hba_rule { 'Replication 1':
        description => 'Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the replication privilege',
        type        => 'local',
        database    => 'replication',
        user        => 'all',
        address     => '',
        auth_method => 'peer',
    }
    postgresql::server::pg_hba_rule { 'Replication 2':
        type        => 'host',
        database    => 'replication',
        user        => 'all',
        address     => '127.0.0.1/32',
        auth_method => 'ident',
    }
    postgresql::server::pg_hba_rule { 'Replication 3':
        type        => 'host',
        database    => 'replication',
        user        => 'all',
        address     => '::1/128',
        auth_method => 'ident',
    }
    postgresql_conn_validator { 'validate my postgres connection':
    host        => '127.0.0.1',
    db_username => $pg_db_username,
    db_password => $pg_db_password,
    db_name     => 'postgres',
    }


}
```

This is the pg_hba.conf:

```
# This file is managed by Puppet. DO NOT EDIT.

# Rule Name: local access as postgres user
# Description: none
# Order: 1
local   all postgres        ident   

# Rule Name: local access to database with same name
# Description: none
# Order: 2
local   all all     ident   

# Rule Name: allow localhost TCP access to postgresql user
# Description: none
# Order: 3
host    all postgres    127.0.0.1/32    md5 

# Rule Name: deny access to postgresql user
# Description: none
# Order: 4
host    all postgres    0.0.0.0/0   reject  

# Rule Name: allow access to all users
# Description: none
# Order: 100
host    all all 127.0.0.1/32    md5 

# Rule Name: allow access to ipv6 localhost
# Description: none
# Order: 101
host    all all ::1/128 md5 

# Rule Name: IPv4 local 1
# Description: IPv4 local connections
# Order: 150
host    all emsa_tdms   0.0.0.0/0   md5 

# Rule Name: IPv4 local 2
# Description: none
# Order: 150
host    all all 127.0.0.1/32    ident   

# Rule Name: Replication 1
# Description: Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the replication privilege
# Order: 150
local   replication all     peer    

# Rule Name: Replication 2
# Description: none
# Order: 150
host    replication all 127.0.0.1/32    ident   

# Rule Name: Replication 3
# Description: none
# Order: 150
host    replication all ::1/128 ident
```

UPDATE:
Want to connect from within the same machine and a Django app

LOGS:

```
2020-06-12 15:48:47.230 UTC [6945] FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "emsa_tdms"
2020-06-12 15:48:47.230 UTC [6945] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 11: "local  all all     ident   "
2020-06-12 15:49:13.951 UTC [7017] LOG:  provided user name (emsa_tdms) and authenticated user name (vagrant) do not match
2020-06-12 15:49:13.951 UTC [7017] FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "emsa_tdms"
2020-06-12 15:49:13.951 UTC [7017] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 11: "local  all all     ident   "
2020-06-12 15:56:46.559 UTC [8545] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "emsa_tdms"
```

After removing the line:

```
local   all all     ident
```

Error:

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "emsa_tdms", database "emsa_tdms_django", SSL off
```

Comment: Please detail: for which user name ? from which machine ?

Comment: What authentication method do you **want** to use?

Comment: same machine, user emsa_tdms, from a django application

Comment: Look in the database server's log file for a more complete error message.

Comment: on it, sec going to update question again

Comment: @jjanes Added logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ident` on a `local` pg_hba.conf line gets interpreted as being `peer`.

With simple ident or peer authentication, it verifies the Linux user connecting to the database server has the same name as the PostgreSQL user it is attempting to connect as.  But in your case, they are not the same, "emsa_tdms" vs "vagrant".  There are basically 4 options here, change the Linux user name running your puppet script from "vagrant" to "emsa_tdms"; change your PostgreSQL user name from "emsa_tdms" to "vagrant"; add a user mapping (in pg_ident.conf) saying that "vagrant" is allowed to log in as "emsa_tdms" and activate this mapping in pg_hba.conf; or choose a different authentication method, like `md5`.

It looks like you were also trying to use password authentication and that also failed, but you cut off the log too soon to know why it was failing.  Perhaps that attempt was coming from something other than puppet, though.

Comment: realized the line causing the trouble is : local   all all     ident , thing is how can i deactivate that using puppet? if i comment it and run the script again it appears and im not able to connect again to the db

Comment: Sorry, I only know the PostgreSQL side, not the Puppet side.  Maybe you are inheriting entries from some class you are extending, or something like that.  Maybe grepping for "local access to database with same name" through the entire code base would find it.